# PHP Make an Array IF NOT then do something

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have come across a client snippet. I want to say IF NOT then do this. So all the items in the Array should NOT work. I dont know why it still does!

```
$StuddedListArray = array("563_black","564_white","565_black","578_turq","570_black","581_blush","584_white","578_black","570_grey","585_blush","567_black","564_white","580_blush","591_black","578_blush","589_black");
if(!$promocode="gcnow20" && in_array($newitemID, $StuddedListArray)){
    // do nothing
}else {
    $promocode_validate_check = $_POST['promocode'];
}
```

Comment: check $promocode and $newitemID by echo them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!$promocode="gcnow20"` is always false.. if you want to check if the value is equal you have to use `!$promocode=="gcnow20"`

Also as commented by [@Vilx-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41360/vilx)

```
!$promocode=="gcnow20"
```

can be written as:

```
$promocode!="gcnow20"
```

Comment: Or maybe `$promocode!="gcnow20"` which IMHO is more readable.

Comment: @Vilx- true, but I wrote it like that so he can see more clearly where was the mistake..

Comment: True. I just added to make the answer complete. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you meant to write

```
$promocode=="gcnow20"
```

instead of

```
$promocode="gcnow20"
```

Comment: What if I want to say if CODE is "day20" and the list includes this then do something?

Comment: You mean `$promocode=='day20'`?

Answer (score 1):

the `!$promocode="gcnow20"` will always return false.
while you assign a value to the variable

use
`if (!($promocode="gcnow20" && in_array($newitemID, $StuddedListArray))){`

Comment: $promocode="gcnow20" will always return true, !$promocode="gcnow20" should return false.

Comment: yeap. that's true. thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

do you mean to say `if (!($promocode == 'gcnow20' && in_array(...` ?  Where is `promocode` set?  You may also mean to write `if ($promocode != 'gcnow20' ...`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want to check if $promocode is **different** than "gcnow20" and the $itemID is **not** in array? Then:

```
$StuddedListArray = array("563_black","564_white","565_black","578_turq","570_black","581_blush","584_white","578_black","570_grey","585_blush","567_black","564_white","580_blush","591_black","578_blush","589_black");
if($promocode !="gcnow20" && !in_array($newitemID, $StuddedListArray)){
    // do nothing
}else {
    $promocode_validate_check = $_POST['promocode'];
}
```